# Отображение кириллических символов в консольной программе на C# .NET SDK 7.0.400

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть простейшая программа на C#

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, Їстівный Ёжик!"); 
Console.ReadLine();
```

Почему когда я запускаю её через dotnet run все символы отображаются нормально, а когда запускаю непосредственно exe-файл то отображается

```
Hello, Їст?вный Ёжик!
```

Что мне нужно сделать чтобы когда я запускаю непосредственно exe-файл символы отображались также хорошо как при запуске через dotnet run, то есть

```
Hello, Їстівный Ёжик!
```

Что делать?

Comment: попробуйте добавить `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Спасибо @ExplodingKitten  .

И я ещё добавил

```
Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

для того чтобы нормально отображались строки считанные через Console.ReadLine()